# Disable Core Spotlight feature in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, spotlight

Is there any way to disable my app's spotlight search feature? I have a pro version of my app and I want spotlight searchability to be a pro feature. Is there any way to disable my app's spotlight items from showing up programmatically?

Comment: Do not create the indexSearch stuff of CoreSpotlight in your light version?

Comment: The app allows users to access the pro version for a limited amount of time, and once this time period ends I want to disable the CoreSpotlight feature. And once they buy pro, I want to re-enable the feature.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can set an expiry date for your items. So if you match it with the one for the pro version for limited time...